# Save `trait Bar: Foo {}` in `struct Abc<Foo>`

Tags: rust

```
trait Foo {}
trait Bar: Foo {}

struct Zxc;
impl Foo for Zxc {}

struct Baz;
impl Bar for Baz {}
impl Foo for Baz {}    

struct Abc<F: Foo> {
    f: F
}
impl<F: Foo> Abc<F> {
    fn bared<B: Bar>(&mut self, b: B) {
        self.f = b;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut abc = Abc { f: Zxc };
    abc.bared(Baz);
}
```

[Try it on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c49b23450c827642ec2ef25d26123de7&version=stable&backtrace=0).

`Abc` stores the `Foo` trait; `abc.bared(Baz)` taking `Baz`, which implements `Foo` and `Bar`, but there is a type-mismatch error when saving `Baz` in the `Abc`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

`Zxc` and `Baz` are unrelated types, you cannot assign one to the other.

If you want `Abc` to be able store both of them using the "base class" `Foo`, use a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html), e.g.

```
struct Abc {
    f: Box<Foo>
}
// ^ Abc is not a template. 

impl Abc {
    fn bared<B: Bar + 'static>(&mut self, b: B) {
        self.f = Box::new(b);
    }
    // ^ maybe you want to change it to take `b: Box<Bar>`
    //   it depends on how you want to expose the API.
}

fn main() {
    let mut abc = Abc { f: Box::new(Zxc) };
    abc.bared(Baz);
}
```

However, Rust's OOP paradigm is different from Java's, a trait object may not be the best solution. Perhaps you should show the actual problem you want to solve.

Comment: Maybe something like using the `unsafe`?

Comment: I would 100% recommend not using `unsafe` here. I don't believe it's needed, and it's highly likely that using it will lead to memory errors.

Comment: @Shepmaster Crutch for create nice API.

Comment: @Lupe Show us what you really want, not using dummy names like `Abc` `Zxc` `Baz`.

Comment: @Lupe: I don't mean to demean you however, what is the chance, given that you did not know about the difference between using a generic with a bound and a trait object, that you would know the subtleties of Rust sufficiently well to maintain its invariants manually in an `unsafe` block? I've been using Rust for a while, and each time I've used `unsafe` and convinced myself that it looked good, coming back some time later I discovered a broken invariant. I urge you not to underestimate the difficulty of writing safe `unsafe` code.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared a type which can store anything which implements `Foo`; you've declared a kind of factory for making types which can store any particular object of a type which implements `Foo`.

Going through some of your code:

```
struct Abc<F: Foo> {
    f: F
}
```

This translates roughly as "Give me a type `F` which implements `Foo`, and I'll create a type `Abc<F>` which stores one".

When you use it:

```
let mut abc = Abc { f: Box::new(Zxc) };
```

Adding back in the types inferred by the compiler:

```
let mut abc: Abc<Zxc> = Abc { f: Box::new(Zxc) };
```

So the type of `abc.f` is `Box<Zxc>` - *not* `Box<Foo>`.

So now you have an `Abc<Zxc>` - not a generic `Abc` (you can't create a concrete object until you specify the type parameter `F`).

Now it should be clear why you can't use it with `Baz`.

Now getting to the actual error:

```
<anon>:17:18: 17:19 error: mismatched types:  expected `F`,
    found `B` (expected type parameter,
    found a different type parameter) [E0308] <anon>:17         self.f = b;
                           ^ <anon>:17:18: 17:19 help: see the detailed explanation for E0308 error: aborting due to previous error
```

The error is not actually on the call to `abc.bared`; it's the definition:

```
// In the impl of Abc<F>
fn bared<B: Bar + 'static>(&mut self, b: B) {
    self.f = Box::new(b);
}
```

This method says it takes any type `B`, which implements `Bar` but may not be related to `F` at all, and stores it in the `self.f`, which is of type `Box<F>`.  You can't assign a `Box<B>` to a `Box<F>` as they are different types.

As @kennytm says you can store different types by making the field a trait object (`Box<Foo>`), which is more similar to a base class pointer in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, if you are attempting to construct the builder pattern, you may want to change your `bared` method to take the builder by value and then return a new type:

```
impl<F: Foo> Abc<F> {
    fn bared<B: Bar>(self, b: B) -> Abc<B> {
        Abc { f: b }
    }
}
```

This changes the concrete type from `Abc<Zxc>` to `Abc<Baz>` in the call to `bared`:

```
let abc = Abc { f: Zxc };
let def = abc.bared(Baz);
```

Comment: `Abc<Zxc>` is sized 0 bytes, does this mean that the compiler optimizes such builder and inlined puts `Abc<Zxc>` in place of the call?

Comment: @Lupe [I've been very impressed](https://twitter.com/JakeGoulding/status/738568045623431168) with the level of inlining that the compiler has done with builders I've created before.

Comment: Does it make sense to write `fn foo(mut self) -> Self`, thereby showing for user that a change is necessary?

Comment: @Lupe that particular syntax wouldn't allow the type to be changed - `Self` is fixed at call time.